# Asset management in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework2

How can be we manage asset based on modules in ZF2

For example :
                There is specific js and css for user modules

How will we assign js and css file path   in user module to show it in layout
as
  echo this->inlineScript();

or whether we need to depend on external module like Assetmanager to accomplish t his

Answer (score 3):

You will no doubt have individual views for each module (eg index.phtml , add.phtml etc)

Try add entries like this to those module specific files;

```
    <?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Happy+Monkey');?>
    <?php $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->basePath('User/css/style.css'));?>
    <?php $this->headScript()->appendFile('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'); ?>
    <?php $this->headScript()->appendFile($this->basePath('User/js/user.js')); ?>
```

Comment: $this->headLink and $this->headScript is appending files two times when calling $this->content in layout the funtion get trigger once again